# Set array in excel row without iterating its elements Apache POI

Tags: arrays, excel, apache-poi

Is it possible to set the values of array in excel row by just specifying the row number and cell range using Apache POI.

I don't want to iterate over each cell for value in array.

Answer (score 2):

No, you'll have to iterate. It's not the end of the world though, if POI did support that it'd need to do the iterating itself, and you'd then have less control!

Assuming you have an array of numbers, you'd just need something like

```
Row r = sheet.getRow(12);
if (r == null) { r = sheet.createRow(12); }

for (int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
    Cell c = r.getCell(i);
    if (c == null) {
       c = r.createCell(i, Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
    }
    c.setCellValue(numbers[i]);
}
```